# Run time - using apply functions

Tags: r, apply

I have two apply functions excecuting the average and standard deviation across the first two dimensions on a large three dimentional array (437216,8,3). It takes 16 minutes to complete on Rx32. It's the first of many large arrays in a database we are applying this script on a regular basis. Any thoughts on how to speed up runtime?

Comment: It's often better to add some sample code and -if possible- data to show exactly what you're trying to do. The answer is : vectorize the code. But without any idea on what you're doing, it's impossible to show you how you have to do it.

Comment: And look on `?rowSums` and `?rowsum`, with `?perm` maybe.

Comment: If you work on Linux then this could be a swaping problem. Have you enough RAM?

Answer (score 1):

That seems very slow. On my machine

```
set.seed(10)

x = array(rnorm(437216*8*3), dim = c(437216,8,3))

system.time(apply(x, 1, mean))
```

takes

```
   user  system elapsed 
 23.903   0.263  24.522
```

FWIW,

```
system.time(apply(x, 2, mean))
       user  system elapsed 
      0.546   0.274   0.841 


system.time(apply(x, 3, mean))
   user  system elapsed 
  0.516   0.267   0.790
```

What is your sessionInfo()?

```
sessionInfo()
R version 2.11.1 (2010-05-31) 
i386-apple-darwin9.8.0 

locale:
[1] en_US.UTF-8/en_US.UTF-8/C/C/en_US.UTF-8/en_US.UTF-8

attached base packages:
[1] stats     graphics  grDevices datasets  utils     methods   base     

other attached packages:
[1] cimis_0.1-3    RLastFM_0.1-4  RCurl_1.4-2    bitops_1.0-4.1 XML_3.1-0      lattice_0.18-8

loaded via a namespace (and not attached):
[1] grid_2.11.1  tools_2.11.1
```

Answer (score 0):

EDIT : After the code provided by OP, the problem became clear. Trick is to convert it to a dataframe :

```
> x = array(rnorm(437216*8*3), dim = c(437216,8,3))

> system.time(apply(x,1:2,mean))
   user  system elapsed 
 107.06    0.18  107.34 
 # This is run on a new quadcore i7, so it's not a slow machine...

> Tmp <- data.frame(V1=as.vector(x[,,1]),
+             V2=as.vector(x[,,2]),
+             V3= as.vector(x[,,3]))

> system.time({
+     Means <- rowMeans(Tmp)
+     Sd <- sqrt(rowSums((Tmp-Means)^2)/(3-1))
+ })
   user  system elapsed 
   6.72    0.40    7.12
```

To get the results in the correct matrix :

```
Means <- matrix(Means,ncol=8)
Sd <- matrix(Sd,ncol=8)
```

Proof of concept :

```
x = array(rnorm(10*8*3), dim = c(10,8,3))

m1 <- apply(x,1:2,mean)
sd1 <- apply(x,1:2,sd)

Tmp <- data.frame(V1=as.vector(x[,,1]),
            V2=as.vector(x[,,2]),
            V3= as.vector(x[,,3]))
m2 <- rowMeans(Tmp)

sd2 <- sqrt(rowSums((Tmp-m2)^2)/2)

m2 <-matrix(m2,ncol=8)
sd2 <- matrix(sd2,ncol=8)

> all.equal(m1,m2)
[1] TRUE

> all.equal(sd1,sd2)
[1] TRUE
```

Answer (score 0):

My systemInfo() is as follows:

```
sessionInfo() R version 2.11.0 (2010-04-22) x86_64-pc-mingw32

locale: [1] LC_COLLATE=English_United States.1252 [2] LC_CTYPE=English_United States.1252 [3] LC_MONETARY=English_United States.1252 [4] LC_NUMERIC=C [5] LC_TIME=English_United States.1252

attached base packages: [1] stats     graphics  grDevices utils     datasets methods   base

other attached packages: [1] abind_1.1-0   RSQLite_0.9-1 DBI_0.2-5
```

The apply function is applied across both the first and second margin (1:2) and the system time is below, which I believe is what is causing it run so long. I ran it on a better computer/system (listed above) and cut the run time some (below), but it still seems like it's taking longer than it should:

```
>  system.time(apply(x,1:2,mean))   
user  system elapsed
311.56    0.30  311.88
> system.time(apply(x,1:2,sd))    
user  system elapsed
505.92    0.21  506.81
```

I'll look into converting it to a data.frame and unlisting it as in the second suggestion. Thanks for all the help!

Comment: try : 'TMP <- data.frame(V1=as.vector(x[,,1]),
            V2=as.vector(x[,,2]),
            V3= as.vector(x[,,3]))'. That should convert it to a data frame, and then you can use the provided code.

Comment: @curransk :  I checked it and it works considerably faster than the original code. See the edited version of my previous answer.

Comment: @Joris Meys -- Thank you so much, this sped things up big time. I'm down to less than a minute for some of my larger arrays. I'm new and have no "reputation" yet. Otherwise, I'd give you a big thumbs up. Thanks again!

Comment: @curransk : if you're the topic starter (Krissi?), you can accept a correct answer by clicking on the "V" sign on the left.